# What's a "consumer-tech weblog/website", and why is it called that way?

Tags: meaning

When people say *consumer-tech*, what exactly do they mean?

What's a "consumer-tech weblog" / "consumer-tech website" (and why is it called that way)?

Comment: An interesting question 'why' as I somewhat doubt that the majority of non-technically inclined consumers realize the use of searching for "consumer tech" ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consumer tech generally means technology produced for, marketed to, and used ("consumed") by "average" people rather than used in a professional setting. An IPad is consumer tech, but industrial grade telecom equipment is not.

A consumer tech weblog (blog) or website is simply a website discussing those items.

Comment: Also, "consumer tech" would usually be written without a hyphen, as Chloraphil has it here. It is hyphenated in the source phrase because it is being used as a [compound modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier).